# list data being passed from controller is not resetting Spring mvc

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

Hi I have a spring mvc web app. When the controller is called, it makes a call to an sql database to get all users. it then passes this list to the jasp and is added to a table. however, when i reload the pagwe the previous list data still remains and the new data is appended to it. Can anyone offer a solution to this issue. Many thanks in advance

Controller method

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/getUsersTable", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView getUses() {
    List<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();
    list.addAll(service.getUsers());
    logger.debug("[User Controller] getUsersTable: Button clicked on user page");
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("usersTable");
```

Table being populated

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<div class="table-responsive" id="userTable">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover wrapped-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>User Name</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
            <th>Password</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach var="user" items="${userList}">
        <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${user.username}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${user.firstName}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${user.lastName}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${user.emailAddress}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${user.password}"/></td>
                <td class="align-center">
                <div class="btn-group editBtn">
                    <button type="button" title="Edit" data-id="${user.userId}" data-username="${user.username}" data-firstname="${user.firstName}" 
                    data-lastname="${user.lastName}"  data-emailaddress="${user.emailAddress}" data-password="${user.password}"class="btn btn-primary editUser">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group deleteBtn">
                    <button type="button" id="deleteUser=${user.username}" title="Delete" data-id="${user.userId}" class="btn btn-danger deleteUser">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

javascript being used

```
$('#userTable').load(contextpath +'/getUsersTable')
```

user jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
<spring:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" var="bootMinCss"/>
<spring:url value="/resources/css/main.css" var="mainCss" />

<spring:url value="/resources/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" var="jqueryJs" />
<spring:url value="/resources/js/jquery.editable.min.js" var="jqueryEditJs" />
<spring:url value="/resources/js/main.js" var="mainJs" />
<spring:url value="/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js" var="bootstrapMinJs"/>


<link href="${bootMinCss}" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="${mainCss}" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="${jqueryJs}"></script>
<script src="${jqueryEditJs}"></script>
<script src="${bootstrapMinJs}"></script>
<script src="${mainJs}"></script>
<script>
    var contextpath='${contextpath}';
</script>
</head>
<body>
<%@ include file="userModal.jsp"%>
<%@ include file="navbar.jsp"%>

<div class="btn-group editBtn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary showTable">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
    </button>
</div>
<div id="userTable"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before load each time clear your html element like this

```
$('#userTable').empty();
$('#userTable').load(contextpath +'/getUsersTable')
```

Comment: ive tried this. However it is not working. it may be because when the page is reloaded the user table is not there. its just the div that i am targeting to inject the table as a moddle attribute

Comment: $('.showTable').on('click',
          function(e) {
    $('#userTable').empty(); 
    $('#userTable').load(contextpath +'/getUsersTable')
      }).fadeIn();